# What's the best way to train oneself to swim in open waters?

Tags: swimming, water-sports

Considering that one is a very novice swimmer, it's challenging to even do sporting activities in the water without a life jacket. I'm looking for ways one can build more resilience and stamina with breathing techniques as well in open waters.

Comment: Are you looking to train in open water, or train so that you can successfully swim in open water?  As in, do you have access to a pool or something similar to practice/train?

Comment: Good question, I'm looking to train so I don't have the fear to swim in open waters especially when I engage in other activities like kayaking, surfing, snorkeling etc in the future. as of now, i do have access to an average-sized pool to practice.

Comment: Have you had instructions and an exam to proof you can swim or have you only tried it out yourself and are not sure you have enough experience? And how big is your 'average' pool? I swim in an olympic size pool, 50 meter length, 3.75 meter dept, near home but had a 15 meter 1.40 meter pool at my holiday location, both were considered 'normal sized' pools in their locations.

Comment: Seawater gives greater buoyancy, but breathing can be harder because of wave motion. I prefer salt water to chlorinated pool water. If by 'open water' you mean a lake, beware that the water temperature can get unexpectedly cold very quickly, with the danger of thermal shock.

Comment: There are open water swimming coaches in many places. Are there where you are?

Answer (score 6):

The straightforward answer is that you train yourself for resilience and stamina by practicing.

The good thing is that strength, technique and stamina are all trainable in a pool, which is much safer if you are not a strong swimmer, and are not used to cold/open water. Before open water swimming you really do want to be a strong swimmer in safer waters.

Once you have your strength, technique and stamina at a level that will allow you to swim the distances you want, then start training in open water - ideally with a group, and using something like a tow float - these not only make you very visible in open water, but in an emergency you can hold them and stay afloat. You don't need to go into deep water, but initially swim parallel to the shore - you can even swim close enough that if you put your feet down you can stand up, but be carefull if you have obstacles, rocks, sharp surfaces that you may hit.

Cold water has a very different effect on your body than a warm pool - and this can catch people out, as their muscles can stop working in the cold, or breathing can be difficult, and it can make some people panic, so be careful!